# CSS compact horizontal tree

Tags: html, css, treeview

I have a HTML that contains nested lists (`<ul>`+`<li>`). I would like to use CSS to display this as a compact horizontal tree.

[This snippet](https://codepen.io/Hojy/pen/OzXbvp) does almost completely what I want, but I would like to have the tree more compact - in particular, **I'd like if the first child of every node was displayed just right from the parent and not little bit lower**.

In other words, I'd like the line connecting parent to the first child always go only horizontally, i.e. (using the snippet example above):

I want the tree to be formated as:

```
Animals - Birds
      |-- Mammals - Elephants - List item 1
      |                     |-- List item 2
      |                     |-- List item 3
```

instead of

```
Animals 
      |-- Birds
      |-- Mammals 
      |         |-- Elephants 
      |         |           |-- List item 1
      |         |           |-- List item 2
      |         |           |-- List item 3
```

How can I achieve this? I prefer pure CSS/SCSS solution, without javascript. Thanks!

Runnable snippet:

```css
body {
  background: white;
  font: normal normal 13px/1.4 Segoe, "Segoe UI", Calibri, Helmet, FreeSans, Sans-Serif;
}

.tree ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 15em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
  position: relative;
}
.tree:before, .tree ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
.tree li {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0 2em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.tree li:before {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  width: 2em;
}
.tree li:last-child:before {
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  top: 1.5em;
}
.tree > li:before {
  border-top: none !important;
}
.tree li div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 15em;
  min-width: 15em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #8F949A;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.tree {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
ul.tree:before {
  border-left: none;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <ul class="tree">

    <!-- Root node (Category) -->
    <li><div class="sticky">Animals</div>
      <ul>

        <!-- Sub category -->
        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li> <!-- Second level node -->
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>

            <!-- Skill -->
            <li><div>Elephant</div>
              <ul>

                <!-- Attribute -->
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Elephant</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Plants</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div></li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Animals</div>
      <ul>

        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Elephant</div></li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Plants</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Animals</div>
      <ul>

        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Elephant</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Plants</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Animals</div>
      <ul>

        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Elephant</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Plants</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: you should make a runnable snippet in the question, in case the external resource becomes invalid

Comment: Thank you @FabrizioCalderan for the suggestion, I added the runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a solution myself: The trick is to add a negative margin to `.tree ul` which moves it up, and add corresponding positive top property to `tree ul:before`, which is used to draw the vertical line.

That is the changes are:

```css
.tree ul {
  margin: -67px 0 0 15em;
}

.tree ul:before {
  top: 67px;
}
```

Snippet here:

```css
body {
  background: white;
  font: normal normal 13px/1.4 Segoe, "Segoe UI", Calibri, Helmet, FreeSans, Sans-Serif;
}

.tree ul {
  margin: -67px 0 0 15em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
  position: relative;
}
.tree:before, .tree ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 67px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
.tree li {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0 2em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.tree li:before {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  width: 2em;
}
.tree li:last-child:before {
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  top: 1.5em;
}
.tree > li:before {
  border-top: none !important;
}
.tree li div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 15em;
  min-width: 15em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #8F949A;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.tree {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
ul.tree:before {
  border-left: none;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <ul class="tree">

    <!-- Root node (Category) -->
    <li><div class="sticky">Animals</div>
      <ul>

        <!-- Sub category -->
        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li> <!-- Second level node -->
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>

            <!-- Skill -->
            <li><div>Elephant</div>
              <ul>

                <!-- Attribute -->
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Elephant</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Plants</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div></li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Animals</div>
      <ul>

        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Elephant</div></li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Plants</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Animals</div>
      <ul>

        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Elephant</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Plants</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Animals</div>
      <ul>

        <li><div class="sticky">Birds</div></li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Mammals</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Elephant</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Mouse</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Reptiles</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><div class="sticky">Plants</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="sticky">Flowers</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Rose</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Tulip</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>List item 1</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 2</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 3</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 4</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 5</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 6</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 7</div></li>
                <li><div>List item 8</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div class="sticky">Trees</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: The value 67px that I used is just empirically observed. I couldn't figure out how to compute it from the other dimensions, on which it obviously depends... It would be great if someone could explain that... that would make further adaptations of the corresponding SCSS much easier...